# Property enabledRendering NOT working

Tags: ios, skmaps

I have a view controller that it's displaying the map, this view controller has a side menu. When I show this menu I need to stop the rendering of the map, because the animations and actions on this menu seems to be affected by the map's rendering, so I call:

```
_mapView.enabledRendering = NO;
```

and it doesn't stop the rendering.

Going further, after I had set the property to NO, I do:

```
NSLog(@"_mapView.enabledRendering : %d", _mapView.enabledRendering);
```

and the output is:

> "_mapView.enabledRendering : 1".

It is as if I had never put the property to NO.

Note: I'm using the SDK 2.3.0 on an iPhone 5S with iOS 8.1

Comment: Can you add some screenshots or a sample project. Does it reproduce on other devices or iOS versions?